# Поворот объекта по X и Y в сцене игры Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

При создании 2D игры пинг понг на Юнити возник вопрос связанный с поворотом одной из ракеток. К примеру, в игре есть две ракетки, на каждой расположен одинаковый спрайт в виде надписи (не стандартный Square, а добавленный в папку assets).

При нажатии кнопки Play обе ракетки (PadLeft и PadRight) отображаются в сцене одинаково, т.е. надписи на обоих читаются сверху вниз, но мне необходимо, чтобы та же надпись на левой ракетке читалась снизу вверх, а на правой осталась прежней.

Нужно сказать, что при запуске игры для каждой ракетки в инспекторе в разделе Sprite Renderer напротив Flip установлены галочки по X и Y, но если убираю галочки по X и Y для ракетки PadLeft то надпись на ней отображается как необходимо, читается снизу вверх, но при рестарте игры надпись на левой ракетке снова оказывается повернутой неправильно и для обоих ракеток галочки снова стоят по X и Y.

Как можно этого избежать, чтобы при первом запуске и при рестарте надпись на левой ракетке отображалась как необходимо? Возможно решение можно задать при помощи кода в одном из скриптов. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно создать 2 разных материала для обеих ракеток и каждую настроить как тебе нужно. Сейчас одинаковые настройки на обоих.

> Нужно сказать, что при запуске игры для каждой ракетки в инспекторе в разделе Sprite Renderer напротив Flip установлены галочки по X и Y, но если убираю галочки по X и Y для ракетки PadLeft то надпись на ней отображается как необходимо, читается снизу вверх, но при рестарте игры надпись на левой ракетке снова оказывается повернутой неправильно и для обоих ракеток галочки снова стоят по X и Y.

^ потому что ты меняешь в рантайме. А нужно менять пока игра не запущена. Все изменения рантайма скидываются до "стандартных".